# Rails 3.2 multilingual app starter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there any one who can point me to a Rails 3.2 multilingual starter application ? so that I can build my project faster ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://kyan.com/blog/2012/3/23/internationalisation-with-rails-3

http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends

or from **Beginning Rails 3** starting from page 269

Comment: Thanks Said, isn't there a template app to start with ?

Comment: to make multilan. site with Rails really easy, just generate new project, then add new lan. to config/locales/, f.e de.yml, and translate just with method t. more info you can find in that book :) cheers

Comment: Thanks Said for the links, they are truly useful, but, what about languages with Right To Left direction ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I consider a worthy short that helped kick-start my project.

http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/i18n_mehrsprachige_rails_applikation.html

If at all you'll need to store translations in the db, globalize gem might be of help, check this cast out

http://railscasts.com/episodes/338-globalize3?view=asciicast